# Can't create initial in-app purchase on iTunes Connect because list of product types is empty

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

This is my first time adding an in-app purchase into my brand new iOS app that has not been published yet.  I'm trying (and failing) to add a new "product" (i.e. in-app purchase) into iTunes Connect.  I've read every thread I can find on stack-overflow and used my favorite search engine quite extensively.  Haven't found any posts that are similar.

Here's what I've tried:

- Go into iTunes Connect and select the app I'm working on
- Go to the "Features" tab on the top of the User interface
- Select the "In-App Purchases" on the left side of the User interface
- Click on the (+) button next to the text that says "In-App Purchases" in the content area of the page

Result: I get a nice popup that says "Select the In-App Purchase you want to create", with an empty list.  Only the Cancel button is enabled because there is nothing in the list to select (see screenshot below).  I expected to see a list of in-app purchase types like "subscription", "consumable", etc.

[image: Screenshot of iTunes Connect Issue]
Other background that may or may not be relevant, but seems to come up a lot in the threads I have read:

- My app has never been submitted, its status is "Prepare for Submission"
- I do not have a wildcard in my appID
- My AppID shows the In-App Purchase "Application Service" as Enabled for Development and Distribution
- My user Role is Admin

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to go to 'Agreements, Tax and Banking' inside iTunes Connect and request and agree to the Paid Applications agreement. Then you should fill in the contact, bank and tax info.

Once this is done, the In-App Purchase types should be listed as they are supposed to.

Comment: nice. shouldn't apple display message their? It looks like a bug in system

Comment: It would be helpful if they had a message explaining the empty list, yes.

Comment: Another important thing is: to accept the agreement, you have to got the "Legal" role.

Comment: Argh! iTunes Connect is full of useless UX crap like this. It shouldn't need a trip to SO, but it's the only option in so many cases.

Answer (score 0):

1. Important requirement is an iTunes Connect user with an Admin or App Manager role, sign in to iTunes Connect to add in-app purchase. Once logged in and clicked in screen. You will get below screen. Does your ID has correct credentials?
2. Clear your browser cache ( try using different browser ). Logout/login again? 
   [image]

Comment: Thanks Amod, but my role is already Admin.  I'll add that to my original question.